# How can i achieve synchronous queries in Android using Parse?

Tags: android, parsing

I have a problem where the results from the queries are fetched after the rest of my code executes. so, i either want to fetch the data in a synchronous way (yes blocking the user App is much better than null). or someone could guide me through a better solution!

Thanks

Comment: You need to fix your code to properly handle the async response after it arrives.

Comment: In general it is not good to block the ui thread. The fact you get a null pointer exception should not force you to use blocking ui but make sure you dont use any data until you have it. So for example after the parse data is received take action. In the meanwhile show a loading indicator. In the developer docs there is enough to find. But the main suggestion is not to block the ui thread so the application keeps on running and does not throws a dialog "application not responding" look for ANR for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Why not tell the user the information is being fetched?

Either use a [ProgressDialog](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ProgressDialog.html), though it's not recommended, and block everything while the data is loading, then close it. Or, use [ProgressBar](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar.html) (highly recommended), and just display the progress spinner somewhere while your data loads, then when it's finished loading, hide it and show your data.